# JavaScript objects: What am i doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript

```
var WEIGHT_KEY= 'weight';

var person{
  name: 'Ryan'
  WEIGHT_KEY: 350
  };

var weight = person;WEIGHT_KEY
```

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: depending on what you meant either mine or Gabe's response are both correct.

Answer (score 3):

Should be like this:

```
  var WEIGHT_KEY= 'weight';

  var person = { name: 'Ryan' };
  person[WEIGHT_KEY] = 350;

  var weight = person[WEIGHT_KEY];
```

JavaScript objects behave like a property-bag, so you can use property names like an indexer for get and set.

Answer (score 1):

Missed the equal sign, a comma between object properties and period for object property notation.

```
var WEIGHT_KEY= 'weight';

var person = { name: 'Ryan', WEIGHT_KEY: 350 };

var weight = person.WEIGHT_KEY;
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/4VxBX/1/)

Square bracket method:

```
var person = {};
person['name'] = 'Ryan';
person[WEIGHT_KEY] = 350;
```

Comment: also, you need a comma between 'Ryan' and WEIGHT_KEY
should be `var person = { name: 'Ryan', WEIGHT_KEY: 350 };`